# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server 2

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to block access to files, but the problem is that when I enter the site like this: "domain.com" it won't show me the index page but when entering it like this: "domain.com/index.htm" it shows me the page.

This is my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm
Options -Indexes
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch ".*\.(htm|gif|mp3|jpe?g|png)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Order/Deny` directives. **Replace** your code with `mod_rewrite` based rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !\.(html?|gif|mp3|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC]
```